# Got KeyError for trying to loop a dictionary to get a counter

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I'm following an exercise on youtube where I'm trying to get the dictionary counter in the csv data.
Heres the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

URL = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/master/Python/Matplotlib/02-BarCharts/data.csv'

data = pd.read_csv(url)
df = pd.DataFrame.to_dict(data)

language_counter = Counter()

for i in df:
     language_counter.update(df['LanguagesWorkedWith'][i].split(';'))

print(language_counter)
```

Any idea what went wrong? This was the error shown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jong5/PycharmProjects/learning/matplotlib/matplotlib-Bar.py", line 14, in <module>
    language_counter.update(df['LanguagesWorkedWith'][i].split(';'))
KeyError: 'Responder_id'
```

'Responder_id' is the first column name.
Appreciate any help, Thanks!

Comment: The keys 'Responder_id' is not presents in df['LanguagesWorkedWith']. Which I suppose is a dict.

Answer (score 1):

Using `to_dict` when iterate over column is not necessary. Try `for column_value in data_frame['column_name']` instead.

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

URL = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/master/Python/Matplotlib/02-BarCharts/data.csv'

data = pd.read_csv(url)

# remove this line
# df = pd.DataFrame.to_dict(data)

language_counter = Counter()

# and select a column directly
for lang in data['LanguagesWorkedWith']:
     language_counter.update(lang.split(';'))

print(language_counter)
```

Comment: Was trying to iterate over the dictionary values under the 'LanguagesWorkedWith' column. Tried this code out and got the error:

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 1):

without pandas

```
import requests
from collections import Counter

r = requests.get(
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/master/Python/Matplotlib/02-BarCharts/data.csv')
if r.status_code == 200:
    counter = Counter()
    text = r.text
    lines = text.split()
    for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
        if idx > 0:
            line = line.strip()
            comma_idx = line.find(',')
            counter.update(line[comma_idx:].split(';'))
    print(counter.most_common(5))
```

output

```
[('JavaScript', 57290), ('SQL', 47272), ('HTML/CSS', 40015), ('Python', 34645), ('Java', 31019)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies, managed to find a way after playing around. Sorry if i wasn't clear on the questions.
Here's the amended code:

```
for i in df['LanguagesWorkedWith']:
    language_counter.update(df['LanguagesWorkedWith'][i].split(';'))

print(language_counter)
```